# How to make my macro appear on the TexStudio Structure Treeview

Tags: macros, texstudio, structure

I'm trying to create a function that works similar to a \subsection{}, in fact I use it inside my code, though I really need it to appears on the TexStudio structure tree just like a section would.[image: This is the tree structure that I would like to appear the \test{} command].

My question is how to make my macro appears in the structure view, as a section usually appears.

This is really important because it is going to be a enormous document with a lot of tests.

```latex
%%TEST ENVIRONMENT
%Creating and reseting the counter
\newcommand{\testref}{\thesubsection}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{
    \renewcommand{\testref}{\thesubsection}\refstepcounter{subsection} \newpage \textbf{TEST\#}~\testref
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{TEST~\testref: #1}
     \subsection*{TITLE:~\textup{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}  \resetactioncounter \resetidcounter
 }

\newcommand{\subtest}[1]{
    \renewcommand{\testref}{\thesubsubsection}\refstepcounter{subsubsection} \newpage \textbf{TEST\#}~\testref
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{TEST~\testref: #1}
    \subsubsection*{TITLE:~\textup{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}  \resetactioncounter
}
```

And this is the main .tex file, that receives the first tex this above commands

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\input{ExampleCommands.tex}

\begin{document}

\newpage

\section{Section 1}

\newpage
\section{Section 2}


\subsection{Subsection 2.1}


\subsection{Subsection 2.2}



\section{Overall tests}
\label{Test Section}



\test{first test}   %this is the command I've created to build my test section that I would like to be shown at the Structure TreeView

\begin{results}
    \resultID{this is my first result}
\end{results}



\end{document}
```